# Is it possible to filter Django objects by a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, django, orm

Let's say I have a queryset of django objects i.e. `Blog` with fields `id`, `hits`, `title` and also a list of dictionaries which represent those objects:

```
blog_list = [{'id': 1, 'hits': 30, 'title': 'cat'}, {'id': 2, 'hits': 50, 'title': 'dog'}, {'id': 3, 'hits': 30, 'title': 'cow'}]
```

One of the django object has a value different from one specified in the list of dictionaries.
For example, I have a blog instance with `id = 1`, `hits = 30`, but `title = 'new cat'`

Right now I do:

```
for blog in queryset:
    for entry in blog_list:
        if blog.id == entry['id'] and blog.title != entry['title']:
            print(f'It is the blog entry with id {blog.id}')
```

But it looks suboptimal and too complicated. Is there a smart way to find such object?

**UPD:** @JohnSG gave me an interesting idea, so now I do:

```
for blog in queryset:
    if {'id': blog.id, 'hits': blog.hits, 'title': blog.title} not in blog_list:
        print(f'{blog.id} is missing')
```

Comment: does `if blog.values() not in blog_list:` work by chance?

Comment: @JonSG I don't think `values()` is a valid method for blog model, but your comment gave me good idea. Updated the question.

Comment: Did that update work? If so, you can use it to form an actual answer your own question with it :-)

Comment: It works, but I was hoping there is some way to do this with django built in functionality like Q or something similar

Answer (score 1):

To me something like this would be the most straight forward solution:

```
for dct in blog_list:
    try:
        obj = queryset.get(**dct) 
        print(f"I contain object with {obj.id}")
    except YourModel.DoesNotExist:
        print(f"I did not contain an object with {dct['id']}"
```